# InvalidDefinitionException: cannot find property with name. How to solve it?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing a Backend app using jpa and springboot (this is my first time) using postgreSQL as Databse.
That's my "Restaurant Entity class", which has as Primary key "id_ristorante"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ristorante")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id_ristorante")
public class Ristorante implements Serializable{

    //Primary key
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_ristorante")
    private Integer id_ristorante;

    //Constructors
    public Ristorante() {
    }
```

I get This error from spring when I try to get any information from DB using this Entity

`2023-02-13T18:58:01.735+01:00  WARN 6304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson serialization for type [class com.ingsw.server.ratatouille23.Models.Entities.Ristorante]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid Object Id definition for` com.ingsw.server.ratatouille23.Models.Entities.Ristorante`: cannot find property with name 'id_ristorante' 2023-02-13T18:58:01.742+01:00  WARN 6304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation]`

Does anyone knows how to solve it? I have another entity class and had no problem with that.

If i add @JsonManagedReference under @Column it works but it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Do you have get's and set's in your Ristorante class?

Comment: Agree with NahuelGiani. You can add `@Getter` and `@Setter` right under `@Table`. Also it's common to use the camelCase naming strategy for Java class members

Comment: I wanted to keep the same notation as my column, that's why i didn't use camelCase but yes i suppose i should change it. It actually worked adding the getter... that looks insane to me but thank you all for your help

Comment: What do you use the `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id_ristorante")` for?